# Neural Net Configuration for sin(x)

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, trigonometry

Hey I was wondering if you could look over a neural net I recently followed on a tutorial and give advice on how to improve it and so on. Currently the NN does pretty well for sin(x) from 0 to 1––it is usually .01 off or something. Specifically, I was wondering if recurrence or depth is the way to go to improve results. Also, I was wondering if there is any benefit in increasing batch size during training. Thanks a ton!

```
import math
import random
import numpy as np

def sigmoid(x):
    sigOfX = (1/(1+np.exp(-x)))
    return sigOfX

def grady(x):
    sigmoidGradyOfX = x*(1-x)
    return sigmoidGradyOfX

np.random.seed(1)

# synapses
syn0 = 2*np.random.random((2,20))-1
syn1 = 2*np.random.random((20,1))-1


for j in range(100000):
    # sin(x) NN training with batch = 1
    # input data for sin(x)
    np.random.seed(j)
    rands= np.random.random((2,1))
    x  = np.ones((2,2))
    x[:,:-1] = rands
    #x is now a matrix with 2 [ random number, 1], [random number, 1] so that I have a bias node
    #y = real solutions
    y = np.array([[math.sin(x[0,0])],
                 [math.sin(x[1,0])]])

    l0 = x
    l1 = sigmoid(np.dot(l0,syn0))
    l2 = sigmoid(np.dot(l1,syn1))

    l2_error = y - l2
    if(j%5000)==0:
        print (str(round(x[0,0],3)) + " ==> " + str(round(y[0,0],3)) + " || " + str(round(l2[0,0],3)) + "; E = " + str(np.mean(np.abs(l2_error))))
    l2_delta = l2_error*grady(l2)

    l1_error = l2_delta.dot(syn1.T)

    l1_delta = l1_error*grady(l1)

    # updating weights
    syn1 += l1.T.dot(l2_delta)
    syn0 += l0.T.dot(l1_delta)
#testing the neural net
x = np.array(
    [[.1, 1],
     [.2, 1],
     [.3, 1],
     [.4, 1],
     [.5, 1],
     [.6, 1],
     [.7, 1],
     [.8, 1],
     ])

l0 = x
l1 = sigmoid(np.dot(l0, syn0))
l2 = sigmoid(np.dot(l1, syn1))
for z in range(0,len(x)):
    print (str(round(x[z,0],4)) + " gives " + str(round(l2[z,0],4)) + " || " +  str(round(math.sin(x[z,0]),4)))
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we should move it to CodeReview.

Comment: [Data Science SE](http://datascience.stackexchange.com/) may also be appropriate.